# c# windows form textbox decimal number format

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want it to be displayed as a decimal when entering data into the textbox. so like this:   1.14 or 0.80 or 3.29 like...
But as I showed in the example there should be only 1 digit before the comma. There must be two digits after the comma.
I tried the codes below. but it is entering 3 digits before the comma. As I said, I want a single digit before the comma. 2 digits after the comma.

```
 private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtpercent.Text == "")
                return;
            int n = txtpercent.SelectionStart;
            float text = float.Parse(txtpercent.Text);
            txtpercent.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", text);
            txtpercent.SelectionStart = n + 1;
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to be more clear? I have a hard time understanding what you're saying.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. the format string is correct. what do you expect in the display if the number is for example: `123.45` ? it will have 3 digits before the comma...

Comment: This sounds like a job for the [MaskedTextBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Use a NumericUpDown control instead with a min of 0, max of 9.99 and a decimal places of 2

Comment: @MongZhu  no. There will be a number before the comma. 2nd after comma like "1.10", "0.80", "0.70", "2.67"

Comment: Note, a comma is this: `,` - when you say "comma" you mean "decimal point". It's confusing when you say *after comma like "1.10", "0.80", "0.70", "2.67"* because that really does contain 3 commas..

Comment: As already stated, a NumericUpDown is the way to go.  Just set the properties and no extra code needed!

Comment: are you trying to make a textbox in which the used does not have to press the "comma" as separator? I can only reproduce more than one digit before the separator if I type in the numbers very fast. Please tell us what your aim is here